# Thymeleaf th:onclick passing two variables (other solutions from here didn't work)

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I'have to pass two variables in th:onclick= javascript. Unfortunatelly, i can pass only one variable, because on second i've got undefined variable. Could someone check my code:

This is the way i pass two variables:

```
th:onclick="'javascript:showModalEditModalView(\'' + ${servicing.serviceBooklet.serviceBookId} + '\',\'' +  ${servicing.technicalNoteId} + '\');'"
```

This is what html produces:

```
javascript:showModalEditModalView('3','19');
```

This example send only first variable to javascript function, but second one is undefined, where is the problem at all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try printing values of individual variables to verify that they are not undefined.

Comment: Thanks, but i've already tried it and they are perfectly good. When I interchange them, I can see, that the second parameter is causing problems.

Comment: Maybe the second is actually not defined and you are sending it. I am trying to say that the problem maybe is not in your th:onclick but in your variables ?

Comment: So, could you provide me a working solution with nested variables if the way I pass variables isn't right, as if. Thanks.

Comment: can you show us what is in `showModalEditModalView`?